# Generate only one word in the list everyday at midnight without repetition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

May I ask if I have a list `emotion=['happy','sad', 'hopeful', 'delighted', 'despite', 'satisfied', 'confused', 'bored', 'awe', 'curious'];`

I want to generate only one word from the list at midnight only, without repetition (until it gets to the end of the list, then repeat again).
For example, if yesterday I get on the HTML webpage and got the word 'happy', then the next day I will have to get a word that is different from 'happy', could be 'sad', but when many days go by (here we have 10 words so 10 days) there is no more word in the list, then it can get back to the beginning of the list or so.
May I ask how could I do that in Javascript?

Comment: What have you tried, what didn't work? How do you want to store this? Do you want this to be unique for each visitor? Then you will need Backend for it... So many questions, please be more specific.

Comment: Generally to do something every day at midnight, you'd need it to happen on your server.  That said, you could fake something like this by getting the day of the month and using a modulus against it.  Something like `emotion[new Date().getDay() % emotion.length]`.  You wouldn't get it uniform for all users though-- there'd be variance depending on their local time.  And it would start back at the beginning of the array at the start of the month, instead of finishing out the array.

Comment: For future reference, take a look at [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052) before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the current date, along with the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) (`%`) to get an incrementing, in-range index for each day. For example:

```js
const emotions = ['happy','sad', 'hopeful', 'delighted', 'despite', 'satisfied', 'confused', 'bored', 'awe', 'curious'];

const dayNum = new Date().getDate();

const index = dayNum % emotions.length;

const todaysEmotion = emotions[index];

console.log(todaysEmotion);
```

Or, just:

```js
emotions[new Date().getDate() % emotions.length];
```